# How to make a dependent dropdown menu using pure JS

Tags: javascript, dropdown

```js
document.getElementById('section-picker').addEventListener('change', function() {

  let WebDev = document.getElementById("web-section");
  let GrpDsg = document.getElementById("graphic-section");
  let DgtMkt = document.getElementById("marketing-section");

  (this.value == "web-dev") ? WebDev.style.display = "block" : WebDev.style.display = "none";
  (this.value == "grp-dsg") ? GrpDsg.style.display = "block" : GrpDsg.style.display = "none";
  (this.value == "dgt-mkt") ? DgtMkt.style.display = "block" : DgtMkt.style.display = "none";

});
```

```css
.consultation-section {
    background-color: #323757;
    height: 100%;
}

.consultation-section .container {
    max-width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100%;
}

.consultation-heading {
    padding-top: 2.3rem;
}

.heading-h, .heading-p {
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
}

.consultation-form {
    margin-top: 3.1rem;
    padding-bottom: 2rem;
}

.consultation-form input:focus, 
.consultation-form select:focus {
    outline: none;
}

.consultation-form input {
    color: #313131;
}

.consultation-form input, 
.consultation-form select, 
.consultation-form select option {
    /* font-weight: 550; */
}

.consultation-form select option {
    line-height: 60px;
}

.consultation-form form *::placeholder {
    color: #323757;
    opacity: 1;
}

.consult-data {
    width: 100%;
    height: 55px;
    background: #fff;
    color: #323757;
    /* font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: 450; */
    box-shadow: inherit;
    padding-left: 10px;
    border: #fff solid 1px;
    margin-bottom: 30px
}

input.sub1 {
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px
}

.sub2 {
    zoom: 1.2;
    color: #fff;
}

.consultation-form label span {
    padding-left: 5px;
}

#graphic-section, 
#marketing-section, 
#web-section {
    display: none
}

.consult-btn {
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: 550;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: #e8576f;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 30px;
    max-width: 150px;
    width: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    height: 47px;
    line-height: 47px;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: ease-in all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: ease-in all 0.5s;
    -o-transition: ease-in all 0.5s;
    transition: ease-in all 0.5s;
}

.consult-btn:hover {
    color: #e8576f;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="consultation-section" id="book-consultation">
            <div class="container">
               <div class="consultation-heading">
                  <h2 class="heading-h text-white">Book A Consultation</h2>
                  <p class="heading-p text-white">Book A Consultation For Your Project & We'll Reach You Soon</p>
                  <hr class="heading-line-one">
               </div>

               <div class="consultation-form">
                  <form id="consult-form" class="consult-form">
                     <select class="consult-data" id="section-picker" required>
                        <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Select Project Type</option>
                        <option value="web-dev">Web Development</option>
                        <option value="grp-dsg">Graphic Designing</option>
                        <option value="dgt-mkt">Digital Marketing</option>
                     </select>

                        <select class="consult-data" id="web-section" required>
                           <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Select Sub-Project Type</option>
                           <option value="">► Static Website Development</option>
                           <option value="">► Dynamic Website Development</option>
                           <option value="">► CMS Website Development</option>
                        </select>

                        <select class="consult-data" id="graphic-section" required>
                           <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Select Sub-Project Type</option>
                           <option value="">► Banner Designing</option>
                           <option value="">► Logo Designing</option>
                           <option value="">► Mockup Designing</option>
                        </select>
                        <select class="consult-data" id="marketing-section" required>
                           <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Select Sub-Project Type</option>
                           <option value="">► One-Page SEO</option>
                           <option value="">► Off-Page SEO</option>
                           <option value="">► Brand Promotion</option>
                        </select>

                  </form>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
```

I want to make a custom (using "div" instead of "option" tags) dependable dropdown menu for my project. I have tried several techniques and seeks help from ChatGPT but nothing is working for me. I have achieved the exact functionality using option tags but I want to make it using div to make it look professional.

For example: Two dropdown menu (First and Second), second one is hidden by default and it must show when the user selects any option from First dropdown. e.g., First Dropdown contain 3 option (ANIMAL, FLOWER, COUNTRY), and each options of First dropdown must contain 3 options in Second dropdown. for example: if you select ANIMAL in First dropdown than the Second dropdown must show 3 ANIMALS name, and same for FLOWR & COUNTRY also.

Comment: Why would using `div` elements make it "look professional"? You're really making a rod for your own back here. A styled `select` is probably more than adequate, and you get select functionality thrown in.

Comment: There are many premade plugins that can be found in Google for this very thing. They will automatically convert a select/options to HTML that can be styled and has event handlers and everything

Comment: I would suggest you investigate how to style a `select` element with CSS. There is nothing unprofessional about its use.

Comment: Is it not possible to achieve this functionality using div, span or li tags instead of select and option tag?